# What is the purpose of .active along with .hover?

Tags: javascript

I am going through the w3 accordion example and ran into this confusing bit of css. The user clicks on the buttons to show the hidden text inside a sibling div. What I'm having trouble understanding is what purpose button.accordion.active serves in the CSS code below. I know .active is used to indicate when certain elements like links are activated. Is it necessary in this case though because it works fine without that bit of code. Thanks for helping me learn.

Here's the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion) to the entire example and below is the css for the button

```
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: please note they used a custom class `.active` not `:active` and yes it is necessary - if you remove it, the element wont remain active after mouse click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise the color of the element would be different when the user points the mouse at the element, and while the user holds down the mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on w3. .active is used to add background color when the button's clicked on. Thanks!